# Strapi custom routes to redirect to public directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, strapi

I deployed my react app to `/public` directory in strapi, everything work's correctly but, when I refreshed page, strapi override my `react-router` routs.

So... how can I redirect strapi to open public directory when i use specific routs?

e.g redirect `/posts` to public directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strapi `/public` folder is here to server public assets and not to host your front end application. And it's not a good practice to do that.
I had to write that before answering your question.

Here is how static files are served.
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi/lib/middlewares/public/index.js
It uses the public middleware.

So you will have to create your own middleware by following this documentation.
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/advanced/middlewares.html#custom-middlewares

So in `./middelwares/custom/index.js` add the following code:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = strapi => {
  return {
    initialize: function(cb) {
      strapi.router.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/post',
        handler: [
          async (ctx, next) => {
            ctx.url = path.basename(`${ctx.url}/index.html`);

            await next();
          },
          strapi.koaMiddlewares.static(strapi.config.middleware.settings.public.path || strapi.config.paths.static, {
            maxage: strapi.config.middleware.settings.public.maxAge,
            defer: true
          })
        ]
      });

      cb();
    }
  };
};
```

Then you will have to enable your middleware.
You will have to update the `./config/custom.json` file with the following code:

```
{
  "myCustomConfiguration": "This configuration is accessible through strapi.config.myCustomConfiguration",
  "custom": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

That's it!

Comment: I'm doing something like this. And for that I follow this link. https://medium.com/@prakash.gangurde/how-to-create-a-middleware-for-strapi-f80a24876fc9

When I set enable as true then my admin panel and other routes are throwing 404. So can you help me to fixed this. And sorry because I'm adding commnet in hear. Let me know if youy have my issue, I can post a new question.

Comment: I can't really help you if I don't know your middleware. Make sure your use `await` and `async` function for your middleware. And also make sure you doesn't set an empty body.

Comment: Yeah I used `async`  and `await` in app. Let me know which data/file you want to check. So I can share it with you.

Comment: Can you add a console.log in your route and making sure your `ctx.body` is not empty.
If your route is called and you receive a `404` it's because the body is empty.

Comment: So, if `/public` is not the right place to host the frontend app, where should it be placed?

Answer (score 1):

I build my Strapi and CRA (create-react-app) at the build time, and says I want to mount my react app under `/dashboard` path.

and the file structure is:

```
yourapp/
└── apps/
    ├── frontend (react app)
    └── backend (strapi)
```

1. add a `homepage` property in frontend's `package.json` if you are using CRA, this will tell Webpack to add a prefix to your static assets, e.g

```
// in frontend's package.json
{
  ...
  "homepage": "/dashboard"
}
```

2. move your built react app to a subfolder `/dashboard` of backend project, by modifying the `yarn build` script, I'm doing like this, be careful before copy/paste my code, there is a `rm -rf` cmd.

```
// package.json in root path
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn build:front && yarn build:back && rm -rf apps/backend/dashboard && mv apps/frontend/build apps/backend/dashboard",
    ...
  }
}
```

3. add a custom middleware in Strapi to be your "view router", that will handle all requests to `/dashboard/*` to serve the react app assets under `apps/backend/dashboard`

create a file under `<strapiapp>/middlewares/viewRouter/index.js`

```js
const path = require("path");
const koaStatic = require("koa-static");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = strapi => {
  return {
    async initialize() {
      const { maxAge } = strapi.config.middleware.settings.public;

      const basename = "/dashboard";

      const dashboardDir = path.resolve(strapi.dir, "dashboard");

      // Serve dashboard assets.
      strapi.router.get(
        `${basename}/*`,
        async (ctx, next) => {
          ctx.url = ctx.url.replace(/^\/dashboard/, "");
          if (!ctx.url) ctx.url = basename;
          await next();
        },
        koaStatic(dashboardDir, {
          index: "index.html",
          maxage: maxAge,
          defer: false
        })
      );

      const validRoutes = [
        "/dashboard",
        "/subpath1",
        "/subpath2"
      ];

      // server dashboard assets and all routers
      strapi.router.get(`${basename}*`, ctx => {
        const routePath = ctx.url.split("?")[0];
        let fileName = ctx.url;
        if (validRoutes.includes(routePath)) fileName = "index.html";

        ctx.type = "html";
        ctx.body = fs.createReadStream(
          path.join(dashboardDir + `/${fileName}`)
        );
      });
    }
  };
};
```

4. enable the custom middleware in `<strapiapp>/config/custom.json`

```
{
  "myCustomConfiguration": "This configuration is accessible through strapi.config.myCustomConfiguration",
  "viewRouter": { // use the middleware name
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

and visit `http://localhost:1337/dashboard` you'll see the react page.

Comment: Annoying you have to manually add valid routes here. I just want it to allow any routes but keep /admin running the strapi admin

Comment: @xaunlopez why can't you write a middleware to accept any route?

Comment: @chishaku I tried but had troubles selecting any route except '/admin' for frontend assets. I could not find an acceptable exclusion pattern for the router.get string arg. Maybe you can figure it out?

But in the end, I realised that it should probably be seperate and use a nginx reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

**The actual answer for `strapi@4.3.2` is here**

I faced the same problem. All you need to do are these two steps:

1. Create a custom `middleware`. I named it `spa.js` and put it in the folder `/src/middlewares/spa.js` *(I am not sure about naming)*. I didn't have this folder before. I created it by myself. The file `spa.js` should contain a code like this:

```js
module.exports = () => {
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    const url = ctx.url;
    // Here you should process your redirects on index.html always,
    // except URLs like `admin`, `content-manager`, `i18n`, `static`, `api`, `graphql`, `uploads` etc.
    // These settings should be completely the same as in your Nginx config
    // for SPA (Single Page Application). Usually, we set up `Location` in Nginx
    if (!url.match(/\/admin|\/content-manager\/|\/i18n\/|\/static|\/graphql|\/uploads\/|\.json/)) {
      ctx.url = '/';
    }
    // let strapi go further
    await next();
  };
};
```

1. Register your new `middleware` in `/config/middlewares.js`. I had this file and it contained only strings *('strapi::errors', 'strapi::security', 'strapi::cors',)*. I added an object with a `resolve` field with a relative path to my new middleware `spa.js`. There are different options for how you can set up this path, you can also use just a name.

My `/config/middleware.js` looks like this now:

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    resolve: './src/middlewares/spa.js',
  },
  'strapi::errors',
  'strapi::security',
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```

Relaunch your server by `strapi start`. It should work. Routes after reloading any page that was reached by React-router before will work as they should work in SPA. All routes go to `/` *(index.html)*

**UPD: Please, be careful. I see many routes for "internal use". For example, `/content-manager/` and `/i18n/`. My admin panel didn't work unless I add the `content-manager` route. I suppose there may be many new routes in the future and we should mark in our middleware only allowed routes that are redirected and don't change behavior for other routes.**

Answer (score 0):

My take.

An [APP middleware](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/middlewares).
It only return `index.html` in the case of a 404, in this way I don't have tpo deal with strapi's routes and just take care not overwritting them on the SPA APP.

```js
const sendfile = require('koa-sendfile')

module.exports = () => {
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    await next();
    const { request: { path }, res, response } = ctx
    if (response.status === 404) {
      await sendfile(ctx, __dirname + '/../../public/index.html')
    }
  };
};
```

You'll need [koa-sendfile](https://github.com/koajs/sendfile)